# How to exclude data based on 3rd parameter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of planet's radii vs their orbital period, color coded by their insolation.[image]

As can be seen by the plot, the insolation value goes all the way up to 40000 times that of the Earth. I don't care about those values. I care mainly about the values from 0-1.50. Is there a way I can exclude the larger data, or at least make everything above 1.50 a different color?
So far I have this:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (9,7))
plt.title('Planet Radius vs Orbital Period', fontsize = 24, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Radius [Earth Radii]', fontsize = 16)
plt.xlabel('Period [Days]', fontsize=16)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

x = data2['pl_orbper']
y = data2['pl_rade']
z = data2['pl_insol']
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z, s=5, cmap='autumn')
cbar= plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Insolation [Earth Flux]')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select a trimmed portion of your dataframe like so:

```
data2_trimmed=data2.loc[data2['pl_insol']<=1.5,:]
z = data2_trimmed['pl_insol']
x = data2_trimmed['pl_rade']
y = data2_trimmed['pl_orbper']
```

where you are selecting all the columns and only the rows that satisfy the condition `data2['pl_insol']<=1.5`